# Glowing stone - Scarab carving

Tags: minerals

I have an intriquing question and, after searching whole Google, found almost no information. I simply don't know where else to look for answer and so I am asking you.

When I was a child, my parents travelled with me to Egypt and there, they bought me a little scarab beetle carved of some stone, about 5 cm long, 2 cm width and height. The stone is white-ish and translucent and glows green in dark (for some time). I only remember that it might (just a speculation) have been in Luxor in Alabaster workshop. But, according to online sources, Alabaster is not supposed to glow in dark, so what is it then?
Can you please tell me?

Oh yea, right. Here are some images. The fluorescence is really weak and doesn't last longer than 5-10min so I am sorry for a bad photo, just couldn't make it better.

[image: DayLight01]
Daylight 01

[image: DayLight02]
Daylight 02

[image: DayLightWithFlash]
Daylight with flash

[image: AgainstSun01]
Daylight against sun 01

[image: AgainstSun02]
Daylight against sun 02

[image: Fluorescence]
Fluorescence

Well, it doesn't look like Fluorite to me(according to Google images) but then again, I'm no mineralogist either so, maybe it's some form of it... what do you think?

Comment: Your description matches fluorite, you can see many pictures in Internet, and compare with your stone. To determine what it is precisely, you have to post a picture. EDIT. After the pictures are posted, I take back my suggestion: the key difference is that fluorite is not transparent, at least those pieces that I possess, and those which I can see on Internet. But in the dark, it looks exactly of the right color. There are very many fluorescent stones, look for example, here: http://www.galleries.com/minerals/property/fluotabl.htm

Comment: Earth Science SE will take rock identifications questions if properly presented.